Go Program for Concurrent FHIR Resource Uploads – Does it Achieve True Concurrent Requests?
I’ve developed a Go program to benchmark a FHIR server by uploading a dataset of FHIR resources concurrently.
The goal is to stress-test the server by sending a specified number (-threads parameter) of concurrent upload requests. Each FHIR resource is uploaded via a single HTTP PUT request, and I’m using goroutines along with a semaphore to control concurrency.
My main question is: Does this program reliably achieve n concurrent requests to the server, as intended? I want to ensure that the server receives n simultaneous upload requests (or as close to that as possible) and that the program accurately measures upload speed and errors under this load.
The specific areas I’d love feedback on include:

Concurrency Management: Is the use of goroutines and semaphore appropriate for controlling n concurrent requests?
Accuracy of Metrics: I’ve used mutexes to prevent race conditions in counting successful uploads and errors. Will this setup ensure accurate metrics?
Overall Program Structure: Any suggestions to improve code clarity, efficiency, or Go idioms would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code (approx. 150 lines). For testing purposes, the dataset and full repository are available here.
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Resource struct {
    ResourceType string
    ID           string `json:"id"`
}

func main() {
    bearerToken := flag.String("bearer_token", "", "Bearer token for authorization")
    serverURL := flag.String("server_url", "", "Base URL of the FHIR server")
    filesList := flag.String("files", "", "Comma-separated list of NDJSON files to upload")
    threads := flag.Int("threads", 2, "Number of concurrent threads within a single file")
    flag.Parse()

    if *serverURL == "" || *filesList == "" {
        fmt.Println("Server URL and files list are required.")
        return
    }

    files := strings.Split(*filesList, ",")
    totalResources := 0
    totalErrors := 0
    dataMap := make(map[string][]string)
    idsMap := make(map[string][]string)

    for _, file := range files {
        trimmedFile := strings.TrimSpace(file)
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(trimmedFile)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Failed to read file %s: %v\n", trimmedFile, err)
            continue
        }

        lines := strings.Split(string(data), "\n")
        dataLines := make([]string, 0, len(lines))
        ids := make([]string, 0, len(lines))
        for _, line := range lines {
            if line == "" {
                continue
            }
            var resource Resource
            if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(line), &resource); err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error parsing JSON:", err)
                continue
            }
            dataLines = append(dataLines, line)
            ids = append(ids, resource.ID)
        }
        resourceType := filepath.Base(trimmedFile)
        resourceType = strings.Split(resourceType, ".")[0]
        dataMap[resourceType] = dataLines
        idsMap[resourceType] = ids
    }

    start := time.Now()

    for _, file := range files {
        trimmedFile := strings.TrimSpace(file)
        resourceType := filepath.Base(trimmedFile)
        resourceType = strings.Split(resourceType, ".")[0]

        dataLines := dataMap[resourceType]
        ids := idsMap[resourceType]

        count, errors := uploadData(*bearerToken, *serverURL, resourceType, dataLines, ids, *threads)
        totalResources += count
        totalErrors += errors
    }

    fmt.Printf("Completed in %v\n", time.Since(start))
    fmt.Printf("Successfully uploaded %d resources with %d errors\n", totalResources, totalErrors)
}

func uploadData(bearerToken, serverURL, resourceType string, data, ids []string, threads int) (int, int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    semaphore := make(chan struct{}, threads)

    transport := &http.Transport{
        MaxIdleConns:        256,
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 256,
        MaxConnsPerHost:     256,
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout:   time.Second * 30,
        Transport: transport,
    }

    var count int
    var errors int
    var mu sync.Mutex

    for i, jsonData := range data {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(jsonStr, id string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            semaphore <- struct{}{}

            resourceURL := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s/%s", serverURL, resourceType, id)
            req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", resourceURL, strings.NewReader(jsonStr))
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error creating PUT request:", err)
                mu.Lock()
                errors++
                mu.Unlock()
                <-semaphore
                return
            }

            req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/fhir+json")
            if bearerToken != "" {
                req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+bearerToken)
            }

            response, err := client.Do(req)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error sending PUT request:", err)
                mu.Lock()
                errors++
                mu.Unlock()
                <-semaphore
                return
            }
            defer response.Body.Close()
            io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, response.Body)
            if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK && response.StatusCode != http.StatusCreated {
                fmt.Printf("Received non-successful status: %s\n", response.Status)
                mu.Lock()
                errors++
                mu.Unlock()
            } else {
                mu.Lock()
                count++
                mu.Unlock()
            }
            <-semaphore
        }(jsonData, ids[i])
    }

    wg.Wait()
    return count, errors
}

